# Validation Error template doesn't show the Error result WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I am new in WPF I want validate my IP address but I have a problem: when I try to show the error message, it shows me only an empty red border.

Here is the `ControlTemplate` and all the code:

```
<Window x:Class="SOTCBindingValidation.Window1"
        x:Name="This"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SOTCBindingValidation"
        Title="SOTC Validation Test" Height="150" Width="400">
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:ErrorsToMessageConverter x:Key="eToMConverter"/>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="customvalidatortemplate">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" VerticalAlignment="Top">
          <Grid>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adorner" Margin="-1"/>
          </Grid>
        </Border>
        <Border x:Name="errorBorder" Background="Red" Margin="8,0,0,0"
                CornerRadius="0" IsHitTestVisible="False">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=AddressBox, 
                     Path=(Validation.Errors),
                     Converter={StaticResource eToMConverter}}" 
                     Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                     Margin="8,2,8,3" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>
      </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>         
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel Margin="5">
    <TextBlock Margin="2">Enter An IPv4 Address:</TextBlock>
    <TextBox x:Name="AddressBox"
             Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource customvalidatortemplate}"
             Margin="0,0,235.5,0">
      <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding ElementName="This" Path="IPAddress" 
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
          <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <local:IPv4ValidationRule/>
          </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
      </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>    
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

ErrorsToMessageConverter.cs file :

```
public class ErrorsToMessageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var errors = value as ReadOnlyCollection<ValidationError>;
        if (errors != null)
        {
            foreach (var e in errors.Where(e => e.ErrorContent != null))
            {
                sb.AppendLine(e.ErrorContent.ToString());
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

IPv4ValidationRule.cs file :

```
public class IPv4ValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var str = value as string;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false,
                "Please enter an IP Address.");
        }

        var parts = str.Split('.');
        if (parts.Length != 4)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false,
                "IP Address should be four octets, seperated by decimals.");
        }
        foreach (var p in parts)
        {
            int intPart;
            if (!int.TryParse(p, NumberStyles.Integer, cultureInfo.NumberFormat, out intPart))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false,
                    "Each octet of an IP Address should be a number.");
            }

            if (intPart < 0 || intPart > 255)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false,
                    "Each octet of an IP Address should be between 0 and 255.");
            }
        }

        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `ErrorTemplate`, this `Text="{Binding ElementName=AddressBox,` should have some error, I think the `AddressBox` name should be defined right in the `ControlTemplate` (not outside), looks like it should be `adorner` (as what you named the `AdornedElementPlaceholder`)

Comment: can you write me some code of your idea i haven't understood what i should correct in my code  my Text="{Binding ElementName=AddressBox, is not outside of my  ControlTemplate  it should be display the textblock Inside my ControlTemplate i am so sorry i am beginner

Comment: I did not mean the whole line is outside, I mean the `AddressBox` is defined outside, it's the name of your `TextBox`. That's why you can't use it inside your control template. As a suggestion, you should try `Text="{Binding ElementName=adorner` instead.

Comment: I have tried to change the element name adorner instead of AdressBox like that <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=adorner, 
 but  still the same probleme only a red background display without text error message

Comment: so you can try `<TextBlock Text={TemplateBinding Property=..` (remove `ElementName` and replace `Path` with `Property`).

Comment: I have a message error : Invalid markup Unknown property 'Property' for type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' encountered while parsing a Markup Extension its what i have done   <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Property=(Validation.Errors),
                              Converter={StaticResource eToMConverter}}"

Comment: hey, please look at it carefully, it's **TemplateBinding** not just **Binding**.

Comment: <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Property=Validation.Errors,
                              Converter={StaticResource eToMConverter}}" 
                                Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Margin="8,2,8,3" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>  now without any error but the same result as before only red color

Comment: Could you try `Property=(Validation.Errors)` instead? (note about the parenthesis, it's for ***Attached Property***, not normal property).

Comment: I have tried with the parenthesis like that Property=(Validation.Errors) in the first try but it gives me an error and after i had replaced it by Property=Validation.Errors how i can use Attached Property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution (after a sleep:). In fact the exact element source you have to bind to can be accessed via the `AdornedElementPlaceholder`. It has a property called `AdornedElement`, `TemplateBinding` does not work in this case because `TemplatedParent`  does not point to the `TextBox`, it's just another Control which is used for `ErrorTemplate` control. So the code should be like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=adorner, 
                          Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors),
                          Converter={StaticResource eToMConverter}}" 
           Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Margin="8,2,8,3" 
           TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Note about how we set the attached property `Validation.Errors` for the `AdornedElement`. Also note about the name `adorner` which is exactly the name you set for the `AdornedElementPlaceholder`. I've made a demo and surely it should work.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was also having issues adapting this code from its original blog post [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121130213832/http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-binding-validation-rules)